# Camel in ServiceMix which http feature should be used?

Tags: http, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I am using Camel inside ServiceMix and I can see that there is a camel-http and a servicemix-http feature, are they the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they are different...servicemix-http is a JBI binding component that has nothing to do with Camel.  If you are building a Camel based app, then you likely want camel-http to consume from external resources and/or camel-jetty to expose HTTP endpoint (web server features, etc)